# Converting one of the value of json to object

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net, json

I have a json like this -

[image]

Now I want to convert all "**value**" (just value json array) to a list of class -

```
JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var alluserdata = js.Deserialize<List<MyUserData>>(rawjson);
```

But alluserdata is always null.

Comment: please provide a text sample of your json instead of a picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got the answer - 
It should be like this -

```
var alluserdata = JObject.Parse(rawjson)["value"].ToObject<List<MyUserData>>();
```

Comment: or like this `var allusersdata = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyUserData>>(rawjson);`

Comment: it tries to convert entire json and not just "value" item